# Profile Picture change Navigation menu MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I have users' login system on my website.

When user Login Profile change picture  login user Picture. I have Navigation menu Right of Site Top corner Profile picture change  options there until not its Working Default

```
Naviagation:
 <span>

 <img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="~/Images/2_final.png" />
@*<img alt="image" class="img-circle" src />*@
</span>
```

I have Profile picture Change  function Working profile page:

```
   <div class="ibox-content no-padding border-left-right">
    <a href="@Url.Action("ProfileEdit","Account")" class="pull-right"><ngbutton class="btn btn-info " type="button"><i class="fa fa-paste"></i>Editt</ngbutton></a>
    <img alt="image" class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/@string.Format("{0}.png",Model.Id)">
   </div>
```

I have code added  Img tag Code  to Navigation layout Shared Menu under View Folder I am getting error like:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<Inspinia_MVC5.Entityframework.TP_InternalClients>' does not contain a definition for 'Id'
```

Comment: What is your model?

Comment: LoginViewModel @sachin